# "Click" accepted indicator?

Tags: indicator

I'm a long time Windows user (no one is perfect) evaluating Ubuntu as a replacement OS so still have a lot to learn. One handy feature in Windows is that usually (but not always) a mouse "click" is accepted and something appears on the screen (hourglass, rotating circle) to indicate that a task will begin (hopefully soon). But Ubuntu apparently accepts the "click" without any indication.  Often there is a l-o-n-g wait before a new window appears as a result of the click causing uncertainty. Am i missing something - is there an optional indicator that shows that the "click" has been accepted ? If so how is it turned on ?

Bewildered Bob

Comment: Ubuntu does have a "rotating circle" http://i.stack.imgur.com/nreIq.png

Comment: In what situations do you miss the "waiting cursor"? Can you give specific examples?

Comment: If you click on the LibreOffice icon on the launcher, and leave your mouse there for a second, it will turn to the circling one that I linked to above.